# Difficulty solving this with recursive code

Tags: recursion, python-3.x

I need to find the length of the longest common subsequence.

`s` and `t` are `String`s, and `n` and `m`  are their lengths. I would like to write a recursive code.

This is what I did so far but I cant get any progress:

```
def lcs_len_v1(s, t):
    n = len(s)
    m = len(t)
    return lcs_len_rec(s,n,t,m)

def lcs_len_rec(s,size_s,t,size_t):
    cnt= 0
    if size_s==0 or size_t==0:
        return 0
    elif s[0]==t[0]:
        cnt= +1
    return cnt,  lcs_len_rec(s[1:], len(s[1:]), t[1:], len(t[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
def lcs(xstr, ystr):
    if not xstr or not ystr:
        return ""
    x, xs, y, ys = xstr[0], xstr[1:], ystr[0], ystr[1:]
    if x == y:
        return x + lcs(xs, ys)
    else:
        return max(lcs(xstr, ys), lcs(xs, ystr), key=len)

print(lcs("AAAABCC","AAAACCB"))  
# AAAACC
```

You should know that a recursive approach will only work with relatively trivial string; the [complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Complexity) increases very rapidly with longer strings.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code, how can I use on it the memoization technique?

```
def lcs_len_v1(s, t):
n = len(s)
m = len(t)
return lcs_len_rec(s,n,t,m)

def lcs_len_rec(s,size_s,t,size_t):
    if size_s==0 or size_t==0:
        return 0
    elif s[0]==t[0]:
        cnt=0
        cnt+= 1
        return cnt+ lcs_len_rec(s[1:], size_s-1, t[1:], size_t-1)
    else:
        return max(lcs_len_rec(s[1:], size_s-1, t, size_t), lcs_len_rec(s, size_s, t[1:], size_t-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the memoization technique, you can run the algorithm also with a very long strings. Infact it is just O(n^2):

```
def recursiveLCS(table, s1, s2):
    if(table[len(s1)][len(s2)] != False):
        return table[len(s1)][len(s2)]
    elif len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
        val = ""
    elif s1[0] == s2[0]:
        val = s1[0] + recursiveLCS(table, s1[1:], s2[1:])
    else:
        res1 = recursiveLCS(table, s1[1:], s2)
        res2 = recursiveLCS(table, s1, s2[1:])
        val = res2
        if len(res1) > len(res2):
            val = res1
    table[len(s1)][len(s2)] = val
    return val

def computeLCS(s1, s2):
    table = [[False for col in range(len(s2) + 1)] for row in range(len(s1) + 1)]
    return recursiveLCS(table, s1, s2)

print computeLCS("testistest", "this_is_a_long_testtest_for_testing_the_algorithm")
```

Output:

```
teststest
```